# Cannot acces java.lang.String

Tags: java, ооп

Почему в записи кода `this.name = name;` есть ошибка `Cannot acces java.lang.String`
Код:

```
public class Character {
public int K;
public int A;
public int R;
public String name;

public Character(String name) {
    K = 1;
    A = 100;
    R = 50;
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас кривой CLASSPATH скорее всего, и компилятор "не видит" класс `String`.

Comment: Не надо называть свои классы именами классов из стандартных библиотек. В некоторых ситуациях через это можно иметь большой геморрой, а все, кто читает ваш код, будут вас костерить по-черному. Может, у вас и свой класс `String` где-нибудь рядом описан?

Comment: @m.vokhm , нет нигде не описан.

Comment: @Nofate Но как же мне это исправить?

Comment: @Felay самое простое - переустановкой JDK.